# Android Element Positioning in an Overlay Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen-resolution, pixel-density

I have an idea for an application for Android. I have a decent background in Android but I have never encountered a problem like the one I am currently facing.

### *Background*

I am creating an overlay activity on top of WhatsApp. When you launch WhatsApp a red circle shows on the overlay activity and it needs to be entered *exactly* above the "new chat" button in the latest version of WhatsApp (Android Lollipop).

This is easy when positioning with DP on a specific device but this circle will not be in the correct location if I test the app on my LG G3.

The obvious answer is that I would create a *xxhdpi* layout too, but the *problem* is that this circle needs to be dynamic, so if I want it to be above the search button, it needs to be there.

### *Question in a sentence*

My question is based on margins in DP on a specific device, how can I make sure the circle appears in the exact same position on all other devices that have the same version of WhatsApp?

Example: On Note 3 (1080p, 388 PPI) margin right is 30dp, How do I use the resolution knowledge and DPI knowledge to make the circle appear in the same place on my LG G3 (1440p, 538 PPI)

### *What I have tried*

- Firstly the dumb approach at positioning it correctly on phone one with dp and running on phone two **(Failed)**
- Second I tried positioning according the width of screen in pixels times a percent (I.E. screen_width * 0.75) so the circle will appear always at position x 75% of the screen **(Failed due to screen density? *1*)**
- Thirdly I tried the same approach as my second attempt but instead of raw pixels I used the total screen DP and used that as my relative measure (I.E. screen_width_dp * 0.75) so the circle will appear always at position x 75% in dp of the screen. **(Failed *2*)**

### *Notes*

*In all tests I made sure that the units I am working with are correct, for example if I had screen_width_dp x 0.75 I made sure to convert the DP into PX before setting the margins.*

*1 - Why would this fail? using screen resolution ratios.*

*2 - Why did this try fail as well?*

*This was tested on Note 3 (1080p, 388 PPI) as base phone, and LG G3 (1440p, 538 PPI) as secondary phone that the circle should move relatively to be placed correctly on.*

Thanks!